# definition/meaning of canonical projection in this definition of (smooth ) tensor field of type

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition

In the textbook of Frank Warner(  Foundations of Differential Manifolds and Lie Groups) on Page 63 , there is following definition (2.15):

*A $\mathbb{C}^{\infty} $ mapping of M into $T_{r,s} (M) , {\Lambda_k}^*(M)$ , or $\Lambda^{*}(M)$ whose composition with the canonical projection is the identity map is called a (smooth) tensor field of the type (r,s) on M, a (differential) k-form on M , or a (differential) form on M respectively.*

I am not very sure what the author means here by "canonical projection". What is the definition of canonical projection?

Can you please tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T_{r,s}(M)$, $\Lambda_k^*(M)$, and $\Lambda^*(M)$ are total spaces of vector bundles over $M$. By the canonical projections, Warner means the vector bundle projections $T_{r,s}(M) \to M$, $\Lambda_k^*(M) \to M$, and $\Lambda^*(M) \to M$.

More generally, if $\pi: E \to M$ is a smooth vector bundle, what Warner is defining is a *smooth section* of $E$: a smooth map $s: M \to E$ such that $\pi\circ s = \operatorname{id}_M$.

A smooth section of $T_{r,s}(M)$ is called a smooth tensor field of type $(r,s)$ on $M$.

A smooth section of $\Lambda_k^*(M)$ is called a differential $k$-form on $M$.

A smooth section of $\Lambda^*(M)$ is called a differential form on $M$.